# Handling Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) with knitr and read.csv

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, read.csv

I have this toy Rnw example where I want to load some data and use the summary function. I have failed compiling and keeps throwing up the `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)` and I don't know why?

I appreciate any advice. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
x <- read.csv("stockres.txt")
summary(x)
@
\end{document}
```

where `stockres` comes from

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b2q/SPM-Ready/master/QID-670-SPMhistogram/stockres.txt

The log info:

```
 > knitr::knit2pdf("problem-knitr.Rnw")


processing file: problem-knitr.Rnw
  |.................................                                                                 |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................                                 |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 4-6 (problem-knitr.Rnw) 
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 0
```

This is my sessionInfo.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_CR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_CR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=es_CR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_CR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_CR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_CR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.0 knitr_1.27   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4       magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1 R6_2.4.1        
 [7] rlang_0.4.5      fansi_0.4.1      stringr_1.4.0    highr_0.3        dplyr_0.8.5      tools_4.0.0     
[13] grid_4.0.0       gtable_0.3.0     xfun_0.8         cli_2.0.1        withr_2.1.2      ellipsis_0.3.0  
[19] digest_0.6.25    assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_3.0.0     lifecycle_0.2.0  crayon_1.3.4     formatR_1.0     
[25] farver_2.0.3     purrr_0.3.3      codetools_0.2-16 vctrs_0.2.4      glue_1.3.1       evaluate_0.14   
[31] labeling_0.3     stringi_1.4.6    compiler_4.0.0   pillar_1.4.3     scales_1.1.0     Cairo_1.5-12    
[37] pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Comment: The code you provide works fine for me.
The error message you get seems to indicate a problem with the data frame
I suspect this is sticking at the `read.csv` step (the file you provide is not actually a CSV). Does `read.delim` work? Have you tried in a fresh R session? Does a minimal document using just `summary(cars)` work?

Comment: Thanks @randr for they reply. 

First just to be clear, If I run the R lines in the Rstudio console they work fine. 

The issue is when I tried to compile them with `knitr::knitr2pdf`. I did a simple example with only `summary(cars)` and also failed to compile. `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 0`

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot reproduce this problem on OS X or Ubuntu Linux. You have quite a few packages attached in your session. Does the problem still occur in a clean session?